# Android - Error in getting user info from facebook login

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api

In my application i am using facebook login to access my application. my problem is am not able to get the user info through facebook login am getting the null value.
Here is my callback

```
loginbutton.registerCallback(callback, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
            if(profile!=null){
            Log.e("User FirstName", profile.getFirstName());
        } 
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException error) {

        }


    });
```

Otherwise everything is working fine.
Can anyone help me out please.

Answer (score 1):

You can get profile details by calling async task from on success of facebook login

```
@Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult result) {
        fetchProfileDetail(result.getAccessToken());

    }

    public void fetchProfileDetail(final AccessToken fbAccessToken) {
        GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(fbAccessToken, new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject();
                    String name = jsonObject.optString("first_name");
                    if(!jsonObject.optString("last_name").isEmpty()){
                        name+=" "+jsonObject.optString("last_name");
                    }
                    String fb_id = jsonObject.optString("id");
                    String emailId = jsonObject.optString("email");
                    String profileUrl = "";
                    if (jsonObject.has("picture")) {
                        JSONObject picture = jsonObject.getJSONObject("picture");
                        JSONObject picData = picture.getJSONObject("data");
                        profileUrl = picData.optString("url");
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        });

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
        parameters.putString("fields", "id,email,name,first_name,last_name,picture.height(300).width(300)");
        request.setParameters(parameters);
        request.executeAsync();
    }
```